# How to disable certain keyboard keys in yocto

Tags: linux, yocto, keycode, bitbake

I want to disable certain keys while creating image in  yocto. I know in users pace we can achieve this with xmodmap utility but I want to achieve this kernel itself.

I checked `drivers/try/vt/defkeymap.map` file and modified as per my requirement but loadkeys not able to generate defkeymap.c file. It throws this error:

`/bin/sh: 1: loadkeys: not found`.

Am I going in the right direction? Or is there any other option to change default keycode map?

Comment: could you show us how did you modified your file ?

Answer (score 0):

The raw keyboard data is *scan codes* that the keyboard driver converts into *key codes* cf https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319787/how-does-the-linux-kernel-handle-keyboards-inputs-outputs.  A way to generate a custom keyoard layout for console is in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration#Creating_a_custom_keymap, so you do not edit a driver file, `loadkeys` requires changes in specific directory / file :

> As a side note, it is worth noting that such a personal keymap is
>   useful also to redefine the behaviour of keys already treated by the
>   default keymap: when loaded with loadkeys, the directives in the
>   default keymap will be replaced when they conflict with the new
>   directives and conserved otherwise. This way, only changes to the
>   keymap must be specified in the personal keymap.

source : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration#Creating_a_custom_keymap

If you want to do this on kernel module level you have to rewrite or patch the entire keyboard module.

In https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319787/how-does-the-linux-kernel-handle-keyboards-inputs-outputs is many essential information ( links to source code, ... ) for all levels, including solving this issue on kernel module level ( writing / patching kernel module )